# Img Src path adding / when using .SVG in Cakephp

Tags: image, cakephp, svg, src

For some reason unknown to me when I try to use a .svg file in the image src path cakephp adds an additional / to the file path which shows the image as missing.

example:

```
<img src="<?php e($html->url('/img/mobile/shark.svg')); ?>"
```

outputs:

```
<img src="host/img/mobile/shark.svg/"
```

It then thinks the file is not there. But when I remove the / in chrome inspect the file appears. Anyone see this issue before?

Update 5/1
On Cake 1.3, and beyond our control at the moment to update. These helpers just break the page =( and after looking at the documentation for 1.3 it looks like it should not.

Comment: hi, I'm on cakephp 2.6
and

`<img src="<?php echo $this->Html->url('/images/title.svg'); ?>"`

work alright

Comment: Wich version of cake are you using? `e()` function is deprecated since cakephp 2.0. Besides that... do you know that you can use `$this->Html->image()` to generate full img tag, and not only the src?

Comment: What is holding you back from doing something like this: `<?php echo $this->Html->image('mobile/shark.svg'); ?>` Will that still print `\\` in the end of the file?

Answer (score 2):

Create a image tag using cakephp helper,

```
<?php  echo $this->Html->image('example.svg', array('alt' => 'CakePHP')); ?>
```

Output will be

```
<img src="/img/example.svg" alt="CakePHP" />
```

Look [HtmlHelper::image(string $path, array $options = array())](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::image)

Comment: Sorry it took me a while to get back to you. I am adding some edits to the post, but pretty much we are on 1.3 and the guy who put us on the framework split a while back. These helpers just break the page.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the CakePhp HTML helper.

```
<?php echo $this->Html->image('image.svg', array('alt' => 'image')) ?>
```

Comment: something as simple as this breaks our page